# flutter saving files locally so that available with Files App

Tags: file, flutter

Is there way in flutter to save the files locally on a iPhone so that those files will available in Files App?

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to `info.plist` and my app now show in Files:

```
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is actually possible.
Just open the `info.plist` file and add the key `"UIFileSharingEnabled"` and set it to `YES`.
Then you're done.

Answer (score -1):

There's a dedicated article in the [Flutter cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) extensively explaining how to read and write files to disk using the [path_provider_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) and `dart.io` library.

Comment: by path_provider you can only store data in Documents(NSDocumentDirectory for ios) and Temporary directory and getExternalStorageDirectory will not work on ios

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mazin, I could able to create file under applications directory however in ios it's not visible under Files Application. I want a way to show a file saved by my application in Files app so that user can export/share it.